# How to use contextualLaunch to identify an annotation

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm creating a plugin for eclipse and I need create a launch shortcut, but the shortcut should only be available when the class is annotated with an annotation (you don't say :p) that I define.

Someone knows how to identify this annotation in plugin.xml? I know that I have to use contextualLaunch, but this is my first plugin and I have no idea how to use that.

Thanks! []'s